# Mongodb How to update documents already found

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm building a movie rating system.
After entering the user ID, content ID, and rating registered in the rating document,
It was implemented by updating the rating in the content document.

How can I update the content document while I have already found it like the code below?

```js
router.post('/', authenticate, async (req: IRequest<IRating>, res) => {
  try {
    const document = await Rating.create({
      contentId: req.body.contentId,
      contentType: req.body.contentType,
      rating: req.body.rating,
      review: req.body.review,
      userId: req.user?._id,
    });
    const content = await Content.findOne({
      type: req.body.contentType,
      _id: document._id,
    });
    if (content) {
      await content.updateOne(
        {},
        {
          average: (content.average + document.rating) / content.count + 1,
          count: content.count + 1,
        },
      );
    }
    res.json({ success: true, document, content });
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(404).json({ success: false, message: 'sever error' });
  }
});
```

Comment: If you already have the content object, change it and call `.save()`

Answer (score 0):

You can update with pipeline instead of use 2 queries, which for your current code can look like:

```
await Content.findOneAndUpdate(
    {
      type: req.body.contentType,
      _id: document._id,
    },
    [{$set: {
          average: {$divide: [{$add: ["$content.average", document.rating]},
                              {$add: ["$content.count", 1]}]},
          count: {$add: ["$content.count", 1]}
    }}])
```

But I don't think this is the right way to calculate an average. You should consider multiplying the existing `$content.average` by `$content.count` before adding the new `document.rating`